# select into a table with different column names

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

In SQL, `Select into ...` copies rows into a different (backup) table. Is this possible if the backup table has different structure (or different column names)? If not, what is the best way to achieve this?

Here is what I want to do: `TableA` has columns `a1,a2,a3`. I want to copy some rows from this table to another table `TableB` which has column `b1,b2,b3,b4`. Content of `a1` to go into `b1`, `a2` to `b2` etc.

Comment: Which flavour of SQL? The only one I can find with a `SELECT..INTO` is MS-SQL, and the documentation for it implies it will create a new table - which should always have the "correct" structure.

Comment: Thank you for the point.  I am working on sqlite.  I was not sure if "Select into... " works in sqlite.  I tried just now, it is NOT working in sqlite.  However the "Insert into.. " works for this.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The **column names** do not matter at all, as long as **data types** match (or can be cast in the assignment).

If the data types of the columns don't match, try casting the values accordingly. **Just try** with small dummy tables. Be sure to list the target columns explicitly to avoid confusion. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (b1, b2, b3)
SELECT a1, a2, a3
FROM   TableA
WHERE  <some condition>;
```

More details in the SQLite manual [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

Comment: cant we do this without specifying the column names like this ... INSERT INTO payment_reject_reasons 
SELECT *
FROM  `de_list_reasons`

this gives me a error ...

Comment: @user1179459: You *can* do it if the row types match. If you get an error, they obviously don't. Also this form is only good for ad-hoc commands and special situations. Normally you should spell out the involved columns, so the command will not break if you add a column to one of the tables. I added a link to the manual.